# How to change execution thread in Reactor

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

```
@RequestMapping(value    = "/try",
      method   = RequestMethod.GET)
      @ResponseBody
public String demo(){
List<String>data=new ArrayList<>();
data.add("A1");
data.add("A2");
data.add("A3");
data.add("A4");

Flux.fromIterable(data).subscribe(s->printStatement(s));
return "done";
}

public  void printStatement(String s){
long i;
for(i=0;i<1000000000;i++)
{}
LOGGER.info(s+"------"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
```

Here in the above example i was  hoping that the tread id would be different(hopping asynchronouslyexecution).From log i could see that same tread is executing the entire process

Log:

```
2018-05-02 03:24:42.387  INFO 29144 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.p.s.p.reactorDemo       : A1------26
2018-05-02 03:24:44.118  INFO 29144 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.p.s.p.reactorDemo       : A2------26
2018-05-02 03:24:44.418  INFO 29144 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.p.s.p.reactorDemo       : A3------26
2018-05-02 03:24:44.717  INFO 29144 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.p.s.p.reactorDemo       : A4------26
```

How i do i make sure its executing asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

The execution model of `Reactor` is that most operators don't change the thread for you (except when time is involved). The library offers two operators that allow switching to threads, `publishOn` (the most common) and `subscribeOn`.

For example `Flux.fromIterable(data).publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("example")).subscribe(...)` would be the way to go here.

Note that WebFlux's model is that it starts the processing of the chain in the `Netty` threads, these `nio` threads that you see. It is thus *very* important that you don't block these threads (that would prevent processing of further incoming requests entirely).

`Schedulers` offer factory methods for various `Scheduler` flavors, which is a Reactor abstraction (more or less on top of `ExecutorService`).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Project Reactor is `concurrency-agnostic`, that is, it does not impose on you any threading model. Moreover, the handling of the events happens on the thread which performed the subscription. You use `WebFlux`, so the subscription happens on one of the threads from the `nio` pool. In Unix based systems you would see `epoll` thread. Nevertheless, only one thread is involved because you don't use any `Schedulers` nor do you use `flatMap` which by definition is asynchronous.

Very good reading: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers